# Authenticating a device before accepting data from it

Tags: encryption

The situation is as follows: An USB-device is connected to a computer and sends data to a specific software, which should only accept this data if the sending device was validated/authenticated by it before.

As anyone is able to reverse-engineer what the software is doing (with more or less effort), the source code of the software is considered to be public for now.

The software of the device is, of course, also not 100% secure and can be reverse-engineered, but breaking open some chips etc. would take a lot more time and effort, therefore the device (and its software) is considered private.

Neither the computer, nor the device are connected to the internet.

Do you have any idea how the process of authentication can be done without the software on the computer containing any critical part (which might be reverse-engineered and reconstructed, leading to a positive authentication of a "fake" USB-device and the software accepting false data)?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Simple, authentication of both sides. ... The missing internet connections only matters so far that revoked keys can't be checked.

Comment: @deviantfan Can you explain this in detail please?

Comment: Reading again, I'm not so sure anymore that I understand your goal ... Your problem is to prevent bad software accepting bad USBs? If both are not clean, you can't do anything. And it shouldn't really matter if the double-bad person processes bad data on his/her own computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is how [some smart cards](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Edinoj/smartcard/security.html) perform authentication checks. In your case however, the smart card is a USB device. The approach is similar:

#### One way authentication

If it is just the USB device that has to prove its identity, you should implement an authentication scheme that is run before the actual data exchange takes place. The USB devices stores a private key that it can use to prove its identity. For instance, the computer sends a challenge to the USB device, the device sends back a response that is signed using its private key. The computer (which knows the public key of the USB device) can now verify whether it is communicating with the USB device: only the 'real' device would know the private key and hence only this device is able to produce a valid response to the challenge.

You may consider a hard-coded private/public key pair if you want to deploy this solution to a small number of devices. If you want to deploy this solution on a larger scale or in a more dynamic environment, you may want to consider using certificates (e.g. X.509), like [TLS](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt) does.

As [deviantfan](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/165599/authenticating-a-device-before-accepting-data-from-it#comment314770_165599) noted, be aware that revoking keys/certificates might become an issue under your conditions.

#### Two-way authentication

If you want mutual authentication (i.e. the USB device and the computer have to prove their identities to each other), it gets slightly more complex. The computer should in this case also have a private/public key pair, and the USB device should be aware of it. In addition to the aforementioned authentication steps, the USB device should now verify whether the computer produced a valid response to its challenge.

Comment: Exactly - and some minutes faster :p. To let the USB check valid computers, give keys/certificates to trustworthy/paying/... computer owners.